# Flutter animated transition buttons

Tags: flutter, animation, button

i need help with FLUTTER. is it possible to have an animated transition when change from a button to another?
I would like something like this:

[image]

On Tap, i would like an animation between button 1 and button 2.
Can you help me? thanks

Comment: Yes, it is possible. One of the simplest way is using Container, box decoration box and a flag to to determine when the button is pressed ( if pressed, switch to button 1, if pressed again switch to button 2) or you can use Flutter toggle button https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kVEguaQWGAY

Comment: Ok but, how can we have animation (like left to righe) between buttons?

Comment: you can use a flag for example **bool isRight = false**. If you press once, set isRight = true, then your change the color of the button. At the container color section, do like this `color: (isRight)? Colors.red: Colors.blue` For animation, you can have a look about this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63611518/change-color-of-multiple-buttons-one-after-the-other-in-flutter and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l0VccGP-ygA

Comment: Resolved with AnimatedPositioned and Stack. Thanks